# Remove html table row using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dynamic table in my html form that has functionality to add/drop rows.  The name of each element has a number appended to the end of it specifying the row number (e.g. ID.0 , ID.1 , etc.). I have written this function to attempt to remove each row as well as update the name of each element:

```
function remove() {

    var theName=getItemNames();
    var counter=theName.length;
    var index=0;

    f.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents("tr").remove();
    counter--;

    $('input[name*="Id."]').each(function()   {

        $(this).attr("name", "Id."+index);
        index++;
    });
    $('input[name*="Date."]').each(function()   {

        $(this).attr("name", "Date."+index);
        index++;
    });
    $('input[name*="Value."]').each(function()   {

        $(this).attr("name", "Value."+index);
        index++;
    });
    $('input[name*="Required."]').each(function()   {

        $(this).attr("name", "Required."+index);
        index++;
    });

}
```

This, however, removes only the remove button and not the entire row as I expected it to.  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle.net example of the issue?

Comment: Can you post the associated markup?

Comment: @macklin do let me know if you solve this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your table looks something like this

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>col2</td>
            <td><input type="button" name="x" value="x" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>col1</td>
            <td>col2</td>
            <td><input type="button" name="x" value="x" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Just use

```
$("input.btn" ).click(function(event) {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

Or

```
 $( "input.btn" ).click(function(event) {
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    });
```

As what you are doing is going to the parent which is the tr and then looking for a tr

If your table is being rendered by javascript you may also have to change your click on

```
$("input.btn" ).on(click, function(){
     $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you have named the function `remove` which does not trigger your function at all. It triggers the internal `remove` function and hence the button gets removed.

Try to rename the function to `removeIt` or something that is not already existing. You can then make it work.

Also whenever you try to call removeIt, do it this way: `onclick="removeIt(this)"` and catch it like `removeIt(elem)`.

Now you can do a `$(elem).parents('tr').remove()` :)

Working example [Here](http://jsbin.com/IdUdUBA/3/edit?html,js,output).

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `closest('tr').remove()`

Answer (score 0):

try this

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".showaction").tipsy({gravity:'e'});

$(".deletenews") .click(function(){
var id_news = $(this).attr('rel');

var s = {
"id_news":id_news
}
$.ajax({
url:'delete_news.php',
type:'POST',
data:s,
beforeSend: function (){
        $(".loading[rel="+id_news+"]") .html("<img src=\"style/img/add.gif\" alt=\"Loading ....\" />");
        },
success:function(data){
$("tr[rel="+id_news+"]") .hide();
}
});
return false;
});




});
```

php

```
<table align="center" width="80%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td colspan="2" class="td3">
news
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="70%" class="td1">
title
    </td>
    <td width="20%" class="td1">
```

edit / remove

```
 <?
    $select2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id  DESC LIMIT  20 ");
    $num2 = $select2->num_rows;
    while ($rows2 = $select2->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)){

$id_news2       = $rows2 ['id'];
$title_news2       = $rows2 ['title'];
$pic_news2       = $rows2 ['pic'];
$news_news2       = $rows2 ['news'];
?>
<tr rel="<? echo $id_news2; ?>">
    <td width="70%" class="td1">
<? echo $title_news2;  ?>
    </td>
    <td width="20%" class="td1">
<a href="edit_news.php?id=<? echo $id_news2; ?>"><img src="style/img/edit.gif" class="showaction" title="Edit" /></a> / <a rel="<? echo $id_news2; ?>" class="deletenews" href="#"><img src="style/img/del.gif" class="showaction" title="remove" /></a>
<span class="loading" rel="<? echo $id_news2; ?>"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<?
}
?>
</table>
```